# How do I push a dataLayer event upon successful form submission? (using Ninja Forms WP Plugin)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-tag-manager, ninja-forms

I want to track successful form submissions on [this page](http://www.themangaka.com/blog/contact/) using Google Tag Manager, and for that I need to fire a custom JavaScript event when a user submits the form.

```
<script>dataLayer.push({'event':'formSubmitted'});</script>
```

The plugin I'm using is [Ninja Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/), and from what I can see it uses PHP or AJAX to process the form.

My best guess is that I need to add my dataLayer.push event somewhere inside the SuccessMessage.php file in ninja-forms\includes\actions (you can download the plugin and have a look inside) but I'm not sure where or ho.

Or maybe that's not

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you change HTML of success message? If so, I would suggest putting your JavaScript snippet there.

If that does not work out, you can add it in front-end.js file in in jQuery.ajax Post's success function:

```
   jQuery.ajax({
                url: nfFrontEnd.adminAjax,
                type: "POST",
                data: l,
                cache: !1,
                success: function(t, i, n) {
                    try {
                        dataLayer.push({'event':'formSubmitted'}); //<- YOUR CODE HERE
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(t);
                            nfRadio.channel("forms").trigger("submit:response", r, i, n, e.get("id")),
                            nfRadio.channel("form-" + e.get("id")).trigger("submit:response", r, i, n)
                        } catch (o) {
                            console.log("Parse Error")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(e, t, i) {
                        console.log("ERRORS: " + t),
                        nfRadio.channel("forms").trigger("submit:response", "error", t, e, i)
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nfRadio.channel("forms").on('submit:response', function(e) {

       console.log('submit');
       dataLayer.push({'event': 'test'});
});
```